# GWT Stockwatcher tutorial - automatic resource including

Tags: css, gwt, stylesheet

I'm following the GWT tutorial ([GWT Tutorial)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/style)

The section regarding automatic resource inclusion says:

> For StockWatcher, you'll follow the preferred strategy. Rather than
>   put links to the style sheets in the HTML host page, you'll use the
>   module XML file. Then, when you compile StockWatcher, the GWT compiler
>   will bundle all the static resources required to run your application
>   including the style sheets. This mechanism is called Automatic
>   Resource Inclusion.

However, they appear to put the style sheets in the hosted page and NOT the module XML file.

Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That paragraph is surely outdated, and should be removed/replaced. You can compare the current version you linked to with the old 1.5 version https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.5/tutorial/style, where they still used the `<stylesheet>` element in the module XML file.